# cordova facebook plugin crashes with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$layout

Tags: facebook, cordova, plugins, noclassdeffounderror

Installed latest by using:

```
cordova -d plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="***" --variable APP_NAME="***"

android update project --subprojects --path . --target android-19 --library FacebookLib
```

I think this results in plugin 0.6.0 and fb sdk 3.16 (aprox)

Builds fine, upon run and login

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$layout
        at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this link

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/537#issue-37034624

Had the exact same issue and checked out
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/develop/platforms/android/README.md#setup-without-eclipse-just-cli

The only difference was `ant release` in the Facebook Lib dir under `platforms/android`.
So built again after doing `ant release` and this time it worked for me.